# Let $\mu : P(\Omega) \to [0, \infty]$ be a measure function on $\Omega$. Show that $\mu(A) = \min\{\mu(B) | A \subset B \}$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega$ be a set and $S \subset P(\Omega)$ be a $\sigma$-Algebra on $\Omega$.  Let $\mu : P(\Omega) \to [0, \infty]$ be an outer measure function on $\Omega$. Show that $\mu(A) = \min\{\mu(B) | A \subset B, B \in S   \} \forall A \in P(\Omega)$.

Now it follows from the definition of outer measure that $\mu(A) = \inf\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(B_i) | A \subset  \bigcup\limits^{\infty}_{i=1}B_i, B_i \in S   \}$.

But I want to sharpen this definition to the expression above, with a min instead of an inf, and single sets instead of unions, and $A$ being allowed to come from the whole $P(\Omega)$ while $B$ is restricted to elements from the $\sigma$-Algebra $S$.

It feels like there is a simple technical trick here, but I can't find it.

Edit: Let $\mu$ also be monotone and $\sigma$ subadditive.

Comment: First off, outer measures are defined on $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, usually. Secondly, by defintion, outer measures are monotonous. So for all $B$ in the set $\lbrace B \in S | A \subseteq B \rbrace$, $\mu(B) \geq \mu(A)$. Also, $A$ belongs to that set, so $\mu(A)$ belongs to $\lbrace \mu(B) | A \subseteq B, B \in S \rbrace$, so trivially, we have that $\mu(A)$ is the minimum of that set. This holds provided that $A \in S$.

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic Yeap, piece of cake. Anyway you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Filburt Judging by OP's question, though, I believe he wants to show this for any $A \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, which my comment doesn't solve. OP's question essentially boils down to finding a set $B \in S$ such that $\mu(B) = \mu(A)$ for any $A \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.

Comment: What if I allow $A$ to be any set in $P(\Omega)$ but restrict $B$ to be in a $\sigma$-Algebra $S$?

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic I've noticed that just now. This is not true in general, as you posted bellow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this statement is true. If we take $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, $S = \lbrace \mathbb{R}, \emptyset \rbrace$, $\mu$ to be the outer measure induced by the Lebesgue measure on the algebra of elementary sets $\varepsilon$ (finite disjoint unions of intervals $[a, b)$ and $(-\infty, b)$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $ -\infty < b \leq +\infty)$, this obviously doesn't hold.

Take $A = [0, 1)$. $\mu(A) = 1$, but $\mu(\mathbb{R}) = +\infty$ and $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$, so $\mu(A)$ can't possibly be the $\min$ of the set $\lbrace \mu(B) : A \subseteq B, B \in S \rbrace$.

If you want something like this to be true, you'd need the $\sigma$-algebra $S$ to be pretty big: i.e, for every $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$, you'd need to have a $B \in S$ such that $A \subseteq B$ and $\mu(B) = \mu(A)$.

Comment: What if I add the condition $\mu$ is also monotone and $\sigma$ subadditive?

Comment: All outer measures are $\sigma$-subbaditve and monotone. See the formal definition of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure . Your defintion of the outer measure as an $\inf$ is an outer measure induced by a measure on an algebra of sets. It can be shown that an outer measure induced by a measure on an algebra is indeed an outer measure, i.e. it's monotone, $\sigma$-subadditive, and maps $\emptyset$ to $0$.

Comment: I feel like I'm mixing up subtle distinctions here. The $\mu$ inside the set should probably be a lebesgue measure on a $\sigma$ algebra while the outer  $\mu$ should be some extension $\mu*$ of that $\mu$ to the entire power set. Does the question become more sensible then?

Comment: Additionally, an outer measure can be induced by an arbitrary family of subsets of $\Omega$ under more general circumstances: see Method 1 on wikipedia.

Comment: If you take $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue measure and $S$ to be the $\sigma$-algebra of all Lebesgue-measurable sets, the statement will possibly hold, as there is a $B \in S$ such that $\mu(B) = c$ for any $c \in [0, +\infty]$. See if you can, for an arbitrary $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, find a $B \in S$ such that $A \subseteq B$ and $\mu(B) = \mu^{*}(A)$.